# How to determine the value of `MaxMsgLength` of queue

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to write simple string message into a queue. The `MaxMsgLength` property of queue is set as 4 kb. The message has 2700 characters and when I try to put into queue I am getting 2030 (07EE) (RC2030): `MQRC_MSG_TOO_BIG_FOR_Q` exception. I am not doing any special kind of encoding and hence whatever is default for Windows should be used.

I want to know how to determine the value that I should give in `MaxMsgLength` property. How to calculate that.

Answer (score 3):

Please remember that the `MaxMsgLength` as specified in the queue definition includes not just the payload, but also the message header *and* any properties that you set.  If you check the Infocenter [*`MQ_* (String Lengths)`*](http://iopt.us/QHX7U4) page and look for `MQ_MSG_HEADER_LENGTH` you will see that the MQMD alone is 4000 bytes.  So if you set the `MaxMsgLength` of the queue to 4k, the largest payload you can have is 96 bytes.  If the queue in question is a transmission queue, you need the queue size plus the size of the `MQXQH` transmission queue header.

To specifically answer the question in the title of the post, you can find the `MaxMsgLength` in two ways.  Visually, by displaying the queue attributes.  Programmatically, add "Inquire" to the open options when opening the queue and use the `MQInq` API call.  Then add the total of the `MQMD`, any properties that you add (including the XML structures that contain them but are not returned in the API calls that manipulate them) plus any headers such as `RFH2` (if the queues are set to use that instead of native properties), `MQXQH`, `MQDLQ`, etc.

Comment: I am using C#. For some of the queues the MaxMsgLength defined is just 500 but I am able to post small messages to that.

Comment: If the value is changed while an application has a handle on the queue, the application remembers the original value until the queue is closed and then reopened.  I am pretty sure that the value is not cached across handles but if you see behavior to indicate that it might be, test by shutting down the app between changes to the queue. Please see [`MaxMsgLength`](http://iopt.us/S9vGDJ) in the Infocenter.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what language you are using in your application. Assuming it is C, check *BufferLength* parameter value you have specified on the MQPUT call.

This IBM MQ InfoCenter [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041020_.htm) explains the case where you can run into 2030 error and possible remedies.